# What's the music that plays on episode 10 when The Blue King comes and visits Anna in Homra's Bar?

Tags: music, k-project

Can you guys tell me the name of the tune which starts at about 9:40 in episode 10 when The Blue King comes and visits Anna in Homra's Bar. The tune starts when Kusanagi lights Blue King's smoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the song from the movie *K: Missing Kings*. It's the 2nd track of the OST, titled "New Kings".